Flatten 2D array of numbers into array of objects with “row” index?
Full-on brain fart mode today. Can’t think of a clean way to do this without an ugly loop/recursion.
I need to take a 2D array of numbers:
const layoutMatrix = [
  1,
  [1],
  [0.5, 0.5],
  [0.2, 0.4, 0.4],
];

… and convert this to an array of objects where each entry represents a value from this array where span is the value, and row is the index of each first-level array:
[
  { row: 0, span: 1 },
  { row: 1, span: 1 },
  { row: 2, span: 0.5 },
  { row: 2, span: 0.5 },
  { row: 3, span: 0.2 },
  { row: 3, span: 0.4 },
  { row: 3, span: 0.4 },
]

Prerequisites:

The array will only ever be 2 levels deep like this, never more. So no need for full-on recursion, I suppose.
The values for each entry can be either a number or an array of numbers.


Can be done with a double loop without recursion. The outer loop will be your rows. The inner loop will traverse the spans.

flatMap the outer array, mapping the inner arrays to row, span pairs...


const layoutMatrix = [
  1,
  [1],
  [0.5, 0.5],
  [0.2, 0.4, 0.4],
];

const objs = layoutMatrix.flatMap((value, row) => {
  if (typeof value === 'number') value = [value];
  return value.map((span) => ({ row, span }));
});

console.log(objs);




Nice! Thank you. Updated to account for number entries. Feel free to improve!

@BrandonDurham we edited simultaneously. The alternative to your early return would be to "box" the value if it's not an array... if (...) value = [value]
